# `in` operator in jq. But, it doesn't work as I want

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

with input like this:

```
{"type": "mammal", "value": "lion"}
{"type": "reptile", "value": "snake"}
{"type": "insect", "value": "fly"}
{"type": "mammal", "value": "chicken"}
```

I could get what I want with `select(.type=="mammal" or .type=="reptile")`. But this is simplified version, as you can expect, this could be too verbose easily.

So I want to do the same with more succinct way like `select(.type in ["mammal", "reptile"])`. I know that it's not valid though, it's a pseudo code and you could  understand my intention.

I tried several things with in/1 and index/1, but I couldn't be happy... What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select(.type | IN("mammal","reptile"))
```

Comment: what..?! no way..! today I learned there is an `IN` operator besides `in` in jq and yea this is the exactly what I want. thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't know about `IN` either. It's "relatively" new, having been introduced in the most recent release (1.6, which is still nearly 3 years old, though.)